# Split Rows based on a column(DATE) while loading data in PDI

Tags: split, rows

I have a requirement while loading data to the table it should check for 2 date columns and split the rows based on a condition. Giving more details with screenshot below.

Today I have a problem with splitting a date range so it becomes two separate records.

Here is an example

---

### | warehouse_id | ti             | tx                |

### |     A     | 2017-02-03 04:00:00 | 2017-02-04 17:00:00.000|

For the result I want this

---

### | warehouse_id | ti_new             | tx_new            |

### |     A     | 2017-02-03 04:00:00 | 2017-02-03 23:59:59.000|

|     A     | 2017-02-04 00:00:00.000 | 2017-02-04 17:00:00.000|

ti and tx are 2 columns from the source table. we are creating 2 new columns ti_new and tx_new

So the final output would have warehouse_id, ti, tx, ti_new, tx_new columns.
Please could you help me here

Thanks in Advance,
Anjali

Comment: Can comebody help me here pls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am not sure if this is still an issue for you but thought of sharing it

i did a quick sample transformation to churn 1 row into multiple on base of dates.

with my personal experience if you want to run it for huge number of rows , push the data rows to staging table in database and then write an SQL to generate multiple rows which would be quicker for huge number of rows as part of batch processing in sql server or oracle or any other rdbms.

image of transformation and steps[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @NK0709. I had to write a query based on this and separate the records as it was getting late. :)